# How do I get a band-aid out of my dog's fur?

Tags: dogs, health, grooming, cleaning

One of my dogs had a scrape on his ear. I cleaned it, covered it with an antibiotic ointment, and covered the ointment with a band-aid.

A couple days later, the scrape was healed, but when I removed the band-aid, one of the sticky ends became stuck fully to his exterior ear.  The part of the ear the band-aid is stuck to is a thin flap covered in short hair; ripping it off isn't an option as that would cause too much pain to the dog.  I trimmed the band-aid down to the portion that is stuck on his ear.  His fur is too short to trim.

Is there something I can soak into the glue portion of the band-aid to get it to release, allowing me to remove it without harming the dog?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I worked some olive oil into the end of the bandage, and it came off with light pulling after a couple minutes; some fur came with it, but not as much had I not oiled it.  His ear appears unharmed, and he had no adverse reaction.

Answer (score 3):

Soak the fur stuck under the bandage with soap and warm water, then wait for a few minutes and try to remove it gently.

Answer (score 2):

Baby oil and coconut oil will work as well. My sister sprayed a little bit of Pam cooking spray and that also worked.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend putting Goo be Gone on a damp washcloth and gently rubbing the glue portion that's sticking to your dog. The bandage adhesive should slowly become "unsticky", so that you can remove the bandaid easily. Once you remove it, be sure to rinse the area to remove the Goo be Gone. While it's not made for animals or humans, I have used it many times on both with great results.

Answer (score 2):

I just used mineral oil and it worked great. Used a cotton pad and slowly applied it to the sticky edge of the bandaid. Came off quickly and was not harmful to his wound.